# JOIN of DB table and internal table produces "is not defined in the ABAP Dictionary"

Tags: abap, opensql, internal-tables

***First:*** I'm working on a existing code and want to add some new stuff to it and I'm really new to `ABAP`

***My goal:*** I want to duplicate an existing table and remove all values that occur multiple times. That - at least I think - works. Afterwards I want to `INNER JOIN` this new created table with another already existing table, but unfortunately I always get the following error:

> Method MethodName "newCreatedTable" is not defined in the ABAP Dictionary as a table, projection view, or database view

***Additional Info:*** As you can see I'm working inside of a `method`!

Here is my code what I've done so far:

*creating new table and delete all duplicates*

```
DATA newCreatedTable TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF existingTable.
SELECT columnName 
    FROM existingTable INTO TABLE newCreatedTable.
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES 
    FROM newCreatedTable COMPARING columnName.
```

*here is where the error happens*

```
SELECT * 
FROM anotherExistingTable as p
INNER JOIN newCreatedTable as t on t~columnName = p~columnName
...
```

I hope someone can help me out in this case! Thank You in advance!

Comment: Joining a database table to an internal table (variable `newCreatedTable`) is possible only with ABAP >= 7.52 and with HANA database. What do you use?

Comment: You'd better read Sandra explanation thoroughly and re-think what you are doing, I believe joining dbtab + itab was not your original intention and you ended with this accidentally

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong your code looks like this:

```
DATA newCreatedTable TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF existingTable.

SELECT columnName FROM existingTable INTO TABLE newCreatedTable.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES
FROM newCreatedTable COMPARING columnName.

SELECT * 
FROM anotherExistingTable
INNER JOIN newCreatedTable as t on t~columnName = p~columnName
```

If this is the case then you cannot make a SELECT on an internal table. You can only make this operation on a table that exists in the ABAP dictionary.

Your code should look like this:

```
DATA newCreatedTable TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF existingTable.

SELECT columnName 
FROM existingTable INTO TABLE @newCreatedTable.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM newCreatedTable COMPARING columnName.

SELECT * 
FROM anotherExistingTable
FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @newCreatedTable " <-------------- Use FOR ALL ENTRIES
WHERE columnName = @newCreatedTable-columnName. " <-- in your code
```

Comment: Thanks for trying helping me out - I've tried but get another error ```If the new Open SQL syntax is used, it must be used throughout. This includes using @ to escape host variables.```  - what does this mean ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, new syntax in ABAP requires to use @ for host variables in Open SQL. More info in https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenopen_sql_host_variables.htm.

I corrected the code. Check it please.